# On line segment subdivision

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose I have a line segment, divided into two parts

[image: see below]

with $B$ fixed. Is there a way to divide the whole segments into equally spaced subintervals $\Delta x$, such that $AB$ and $BC$ are both multiple of $\Delta x$?

Comment: should the subintervals be of integer lengths?

Comment: In general, no. Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_(mathematics)

Comment: This can only be done if the ratio $|AB| : |BC|$ is rational.

Comment: Can this be true in the limit (as $\Delta x\to0$)?

Comment: What does it mean for it to be true in the limit?

Comment: Sorry, I said that badly. I mean, can this be done if I take infinitesimal subintervals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can only do it if both parts have rational length or are multiples of the same irrational number. So the greeks allready proved that you can not divide the diagonal of a square and the side of the square in the same finite $\Delta x$